# ALTER INDEX taking long time on Oracle

Tags: indexing, oracle11g, alter, partition

I have table which partitioned by date and index is different table space.
So first I tried this query.

```
ALTER TABLE USER.XXX TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION SP_201508_D11 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

But it's never finish.

So removed this part `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` and it was truncated very fast. After that my index is broken then run following query.

```
ALTER INDEX USER.IDX_XXX
REBUILD
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
TABLESPACE TB_S
STORAGE (
         INITIAL     64K
         NEXT        10M
        )
```

And it's looks also never finish. How can I handle this issue? Index size is about 50GB.

Comment: How long have you left it running? I expect it will finish, it will just take longer than you have left it.

Comment: 1 hour then it inactive, our network can keep session for just 1 hour

Comment: If your problem is that your network is killing the connection before the statement completes, you'd want to submit a job to do the alter that can run on the server without needing your connection to remain up.

Comment: OK, how long do you want it to take? It is possible that it will just take over an hour (see Justin's advice).